# Jquery to Javascript: Toggle class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".show_on_hover").click(function() {
        $(".show_on_hover.hover").not(this).removeClass("hover");
        $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    });

});
```

Any clever JavaScript person know how to write the above as plain JavaScript? Thanks in advance :)

Here's the intended behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/kevadamson/fr8usm19/

Comment: What have you tried so far? [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) will get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your original (using jQuery):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".show_on_hover").click(function() {
        $(".show_on_hover.hover").not(this).removeClass("hover");
        $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    });

});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show_on_hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.show_on_hover:hover,
.show_on_hover.hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="show_on_hover"></div>
<div class="show_on_hover"></div>
<div class="show_on_hover"></div>
<div class="show_on_hover"></div>
<div class="show_on_hover"></div>
```

Here is the same setup, with jQuery translated into javascript:

```js
// Equivalent to $(".show_on_hover")
let showOnHoverDivs = [...document.getElementsByClassName('show_on_hover')];

const showHideDivs = (event) => {

  for (let showOnHoverDiv of showOnHoverDivs) {
    
    // Equivalent to .not(this)
    if (showOnHoverDiv === event.target) continue;
    
    // Equivalent to .removeClass("hover")
    showOnHoverDiv.classList.remove('hover');
  }
  
  // Equivalent to $(this).toggleClass("hover")
  event.target.classList.toggle('hover');
}

// Equivalent to $(".show_on_hover").click(function() { [...] }
for (let showOnHoverDiv of showOnHoverDivs) {
  showOnHoverDiv.addEventListener('click', showHideDivs, false);
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show_on_hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.show_on_hover:hover,
.show_on_hover.hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="show_on_hover"></div>
<div class="show_on_hover"></div>
<div class="show_on_hover"></div>
<div class="show_on_hover"></div>
<div class="show_on_hover"></div>
```

Comment: Sure thing. Do ask if there's anything you're not sure about or if there is any part of the javascript syntax which doesn't immediately make sense to you. With only 10-12 building blocks committed to memory you'll find it starts becoming very straightforward to translate jQuery into vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Add click listener only for the first element with class `.show_on_hover`:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.show_on_hover');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (btn.classList.contains('hover')) {
    btn.classList.remove('hover');
  } else {
    btn.classList.add('hover');
  }
})
```

Add click listener for each element with class `.show_on_hover`:

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.show_on_hover');
btns.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (btn.classList.contains('hover')) {
    el.classList.remove('hover');
  } else {
    el.classList.add('hover');
  }
}));
```

Comment: Thanks :) Missing `)` after `contains('hover')`?

Comment: Seems to work at adding and removing on the first instance on the page, but other instances not working ...

Comment: You wan't to handle click from all buttons with this class?

Comment: Yes please. All instances need to toggle on click, but then remove other instances from the page also, so only one instance ever has the lass added - make sense?

Comment: This now toggles the class on the first when clicking all the others. The intended behavior is as follows:

a) When I click the item it adds the class, then click it again it removes it
b) If another instance of `show_on_hover` on the page has been clicked and has class of `hover` it is removed when a different instance is clicked, therefore only one instance can have class of `hover` at any one time

Comment: Fixed (second example)

Comment: Still not working I don't think :( If it helps, here's the intended behavior but using jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/kevadamson/fr8usm19/ < note toggle and also removal from others

Answer (score -1):

you can use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

you can do toggle, remove, add, and also with condition

```
var btn = document.querySelector('.show_on_hover')
btn.classList.toggle('hover);
```